# why damage video when marage video android studio

Tags: java, android, audio, merge, video-streaming

I made many converters, but every time I fail, I hope someone will answer me, I use the following code in the process of merging MP4 video files together, but every time the video gets distorted in a very bad way, but the file keeps the sound quality I used before Mp4parser library, but it did not work and the file continued to be damaged, but the file also keeps its audio quality

VideoCombiner.class:

```
public class VideoCombiner {
 
    private static final String TAG = "VideoCombiner";
    private static final boolean VERBOSE = true;
 
         // maximum buffer (1024 x 1024 = 1048576, 1920 x 1080 = 2073600)
         // Since there is no 1080P video recorded, use 1024 Buffer to cache
    private static final int MAX_BUFF_SIZE = 1048576;
 
    private List<String> mVideoList;
    private String mDestPath;
 
    private MediaMuxer mMuxer;
    private ByteBuffer mReadBuf;
    private int mOutAudioTrackIndex;
    private int mOutVideoTrackIndex;
    private MediaFormat mAudioFormat;
    private MediaFormat mVideoFormat;
 
    private VideoCombineListener mCombineListener;
 
    public interface VideoCombineListener {
 
        /**
                   * Start of merger
         */
        void onCombineStart();
 
        /**
                   * Merger process
                   * @param current currently merged video
                   * @param sum Total number of merged videos
         */
        void onCombineProcessing(int current, int sum);
 
        /**
                   * End of merger
                   * @param success Whether the merge was successful
         */
        void onCombineFinished(boolean success);
    }
 
 
 
    public VideoCombiner(List<String> videoList, String destPath, VideoCombineListener listener) {
        mVideoList = videoList;
        mDestPath = destPath;
        mCombineListener = listener;
        mReadBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_BUFF_SIZE);
    }
 
    /**
           * Combined video
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    public void combineVideo() {
        boolean hasAudioFormat = false;
        boolean hasVideoFormat = false;
        Iterator videoIterator = mVideoList.iterator();
 
                 // start merging
        if (mCombineListener != null) {
            mCombineListener.onCombineStart();
        }
 
                 // MediaExtractor gets multimedia information for MediaMuxer to create files
        while (videoIterator.hasNext()) {
            String videoPath = (String) videoIterator.next();
            MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
            try {
                extractor.setDataSource(videoPath);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
 
            int trackIndex;
            if (!hasVideoFormat) {
                trackIndex = selectTrack(extractor, "video/");
                if(trackIndex < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "No video track found in " + videoPath);
                } else {
                    extractor.selectTrack(trackIndex);
                    mVideoFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(trackIndex);
                    hasVideoFormat = true;
                }
            }
 
            if (!hasAudioFormat) {
                trackIndex = selectTrack(extractor, "audio/");
                if(trackIndex < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "No audio track found in " + videoPath);
                } else {
                    extractor.selectTrack(trackIndex);
                    mAudioFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(trackIndex);
                    hasAudioFormat = true;
                }
            }
 
            extractor.release();
 
            if (hasVideoFormat && hasAudioFormat) {
                break;
            }
        }
 
        try {
            mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(mDestPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        if (hasVideoFormat) {
            mOutVideoTrackIndex = mMuxer.addTrack(mVideoFormat);
        }
 
        if (hasAudioFormat) {
            mOutAudioTrackIndex = mMuxer.addTrack(mAudioFormat);
        }
        mMuxer.start();
 
                 // MediaExtractor traverses the read frame, MediaMuxer writes the frame, and records the frame information
        long ptsOffset = 0L;
        Iterator trackIndex = mVideoList.iterator();
        int currentVideo = 0;
        boolean combineResult = true;
        while (trackIndex.hasNext()) {
                         / / Listen to the current merged video
            currentVideo++;
            if (mCombineListener != null) {
                mCombineListener.onCombineProcessing(currentVideo, mVideoList.size());
            }
 
            String videoPath = (String) trackIndex.next();
            boolean hasVideo = true;
            boolean hasAudio = true;
 
                         // Select video track
            MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
            try {
                videoExtractor.setDataSource(videoPath);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int inVideoTrackIndex = selectTrack(videoExtractor, "video/");
            if(inVideoTrackIndex < 0) {
                hasVideo = false;
            }
            videoExtractor.selectTrack(inVideoTrackIndex);
 
                         // Select an audio track
            MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
            try {
                audioExtractor.setDataSource(videoPath);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int inAudioTrackIndex = selectTrack(audioExtractor, "audio/");
            if (inAudioTrackIndex < 0) {
                hasAudio = false;
            }
            audioExtractor.selectTrack(inAudioTrackIndex);
 
                         // If there are no video tracks and audio tracks, the merge fails and the file fails.
            if (!hasVideo && !hasAudio) {
 
                combineResult = false;
 
                videoExtractor.release();
                audioExtractor.release();
 
                break;
            }
 
            boolean bMediaDone = false;
            long presentationTimeUs = 0L;
            long audioPts = 0L;
            long videoPts = 0L;
 
            while (!bMediaDone) {
                                 / / Determine whether there is audio and video
                if(!hasVideo && !hasAudio) {
                    break;
                }
 
                int outTrackIndex;
                MediaExtractor extractor;
                int currentTrackIndex;
                if ((!hasVideo || audioPts - videoPts <= 50000L) && hasAudio) {
                    currentTrackIndex = inAudioTrackIndex;
                    outTrackIndex = mOutAudioTrackIndex;
                    extractor = audioExtractor;
                } else {
                    currentTrackIndex = inVideoTrackIndex;
                    outTrackIndex = mOutVideoTrackIndex;
                    extractor = videoExtractor;
                }
 
                if (VERBOSE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "currentTrackIndex： " + currentTrackIndex
                            + ", outTrackIndex: " + outTrackIndex);
                }
 
                mReadBuf.rewind();
                                 // read the data frame
                int frameSize = extractor.readSampleData(mReadBuf, 0);
                if (frameSize < 0) {
                    if (currentTrackIndex == inVideoTrackIndex) {
                        hasVideo = false;
                    } else if (currentTrackIndex == inAudioTrackIndex) {
                        hasAudio = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (extractor.getSampleTrackIndex() != currentTrackIndex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "got sample from track "
                                + extractor.getSampleTrackIndex()
                                + ", expected " + currentTrackIndex);
                    }
 
                                         // read the pts of the frame
                    presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
                    if (currentTrackIndex == inVideoTrackIndex) {
                        videoPts = presentationTimeUs;
                    } else {
                        audioPts = presentationTimeUs;
                    }
 
                                         // frame information
                    BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
                    info.offset = 0;
                    info.size = frameSize;
                    info.presentationTimeUs = ptsOffset + presentationTimeUs;
 
                    if ((extractor.getSampleFlags() & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME) != 0) {
                        info.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME;
                    }
                    mReadBuf.rewind();
                    if (VERBOSE) {
                        Log.d(TAG, String.format("write sample track %d, size %d, pts %d flag %d",
                                Integer.valueOf(outTrackIndex),
                                Integer.valueOf(info.size),
                                Long.valueOf(info.presentationTimeUs),
                                Integer.valueOf(info.flags))
                        );
                    }
                                         / / Write the read data to the file
                    mMuxer.writeSampleData(outTrackIndex, mReadBuf, info);
                    extractor.advance();
                }
            }
 
                         // PTS of the last frame of the current file, used as the pts of the next video
            ptsOffset += videoPts > audioPts ? videoPts : audioPts;
                         // The difference between the last frame and the next frame of the current file is 40ms. By default, the video is recorded at 25fps, and the frame interval is 40ms.
                         // But after recording with MediaCodec, an OES frame is written later, causing a time difference in the previous parsing.
                         // The 10ms effect here is better than 40ms.
            ptsOffset += 10000L;
 
            if (VERBOSE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "finish one file, ptsOffset " + ptsOffset);
            }
 
                         // free resources
            videoExtractor.release();
            audioExtractor.release();
        }
 
                 // release the multiplexer
        if (mMuxer != null) {
            try {
                mMuxer.stop();
                mMuxer.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Muxer close error. No data was written");
            } finally {
                mMuxer = null;
            }
        }
 
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "video combine finished");
        }
 
                 // End of merger
        if (mCombineListener != null) {
            mCombineListener.onCombineFinished(combineResult);
        }
    }
 
    /**
           * Select track
     * @param extractor     MediaExtractor
           * @param mimePrefix track or track
     * @return
     */
    private int selectTrack(MediaExtractor extractor, String mimePrefix) {
                 // Get the total number of tracks
        int numTracks = extractor.getTrackCount();
                 / / Traverse to find the track containing mimePrefix
        for(int i = 0; i < numTracks; ++i) {
            MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = format.getString("mime");
            if (mime.startsWith(mimePrefix)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
 
        return -1;
    }
```

VideoCombineManager.class :

```
public final class VideoCombineManager {


private static final String TAG = "VideoCombineManage";

private static VideoCombineManager mInstance;


public static VideoCombineManager getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new VideoCombineManager();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

/**
       * Initialize the media merger
 * @param videoPath
 * @param destPath
 */
public void startVideoCombiner(final List<String> videoPath, final String destPath,
                               final VideoCombiner.VideoCombineListener listener) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            VideoCombiner videoCombiner = new VideoCombiner(videoPath, destPath, listener);
            videoCombiner.combineVideo();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}